# « Spectre toujours masqué qui nous suis côte à côte » : pourquoi pas « suit » (3e sing.) ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, latin, littérature

> Ô fantôme muet, ô notre ombre, ô notre hôte,
>  Spectre toujours
>   masqué qui nous **suis** côte à côte,
>  Et qu’on nomme demain !
>   
>   [ [Victor Hugo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Hugo), [*Napoléon II*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Napol%C3%A9on_II) - ds. *Les Chants du crépuscule*,
>   extrait ]

Dans le deuxième vers de l'extrait, on a un sujet (*spectre*) et un pronom relatif (*qui*) qui y fait référence et puis un accord du verbe [*suivre*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/suivre/75316) qui n'est pas à la troisième personne du singulier (*suit*).

Comment et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le verbe n'est pas à la troisième personne du singulier tout simplement parce qu'il est à la deuxième personne du singulier, puisque le sujet est la personne à qui s'adresse le discours. La deuxième personne ne nécessite pas le pronom *tu*, c'est seulement le cas le plus courant.

Prenons un exemple simple où le sujet est un pronom relatif :

> Toi qui es grand, attrape ce livre sur l'étagère du haut.

Le sujet de *es* est *qui*, mais c'est l'interlocuteur, donc on conjugue à la deuxième personne. On ferait de même à la première personne :

> Moi qui suis grand, je peux attraper ce livre sur l'étagère du haut.

Il est nettement plus rare de se passer de *tu* dans une proposition principale. Dans mon premier exemple, « toi qui est grand » n'est pas le sujet du verbe *attraper*, c'est une apostrophe ; le verbe *attraper* est à l'impératif et n'a donc pas de sujet grammatical. Dans mon deuxième exemple, le sujet est repris par le pronom *je*. En français moderne, je crois même que la reprise du pronom est indispensable, mais on pourrait trouver une construction comme « (?) moi qui suis grand puis attraper ce livre » dans la langue littéraire classique, et surtout en poésie.

Answer (score 7):

Les vers précédents expliquent tout : il parle au fantôme / spectre.

> Nul ne **te** fait parler, nul ne peut avant l'heure
>
> Ouvrir **ta** main froide.

Le verbe est donc *(tu) suis* et non pas *(il) suit*.

Comment: Il s'agit donc de 《**toi** qui nous suis》.

Answer (score 4):

Il s'agit d'une [*apostrophe*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apostrophe) ([2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe_%28rh%C3%A9torique%29)) ou d'une *interpellation*, et « [ô](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%B4) », généralement une [interjection](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%B4%C2%A0_/55329/difficulte), en est souvent l'[introducteur](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=vocatif&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) spécifique dans la langue littéraire. La particularité est que « *[l]e mot en apostrophe appartient à la **deuxième personne** grammaticale* » (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, au §376, que l'on consultera pour plus de détails), ce qui correspond au *vocatif*<sup>1</sup> en latin, d'où (tu) *suis* :

> Adieu, meuse endormeuse et douce à mon enfance,
>  Qui demeures aux
>   prés, où tu coules tout bas
>
> [ Peguy, *Morceaux choisis*]

Il ne faut pas confondre ces cas avec ceux de l'*apposition* et de l'*injure* (+ impératif, par exemple). On dit (*LBU*) cependant que la nuance est en effet parfois assez *subtile* et l'exemple présenté ainsi que le suivant sont donc matière à réflexion :

> Ô plaisir, bélier qui te fêles le front et qui recommences.
>
> [ Colette, *Le pur et l'impur*, Pl. ]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Tel le fameux [prototype](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque_mi_fili) césarien « *tu quoque, [filī](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=filius)* » , que César a sans doute dit en [grec](https://books.google.com/books?id=170DKOpuK1QC&lpg=PA181&dq=%22tu%20quoque%20fili%22&hl=fr&pg=PA181#v=onepage&q=%22tu%20quoque%20fili%22&f=false), si du tout.</sub>